# Set specific elements on a matrix to zero

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to preserve some elements in a 36x18x12000 matrix and set everything else to zero. In particular, I'm interested in getting the values of a specific region in the 36x18 map through time. The code I'm trying to use for this is the following:

```
coflux_SAm(1:26,1:3,:)=0;coflux_SAm(35:36,11:18,:)=0
```

What I plan to do here is to keep the South American region (lon 27:34 ; lat 4:10 in the map) and delete the rest, basically. I'm getting pretty annoyed of finding that neither this line nor the loop:

```
for i=1:26
    for j=1:3
        coflux_SAm(i,j,:)=0;
    end
end

for i=35:36
    for j=11:18
        coflux_SAm(i,j,:)=0;
    end
end
```

are working. They seem to make random modifications in the matrix but I don't even find a pattern to it.

Comment: Ok, nevermind...I was obviously being silly and getting worried about the code and not the logic behind what I really wanted. I changed the code to: 'coflux_SAm(1:26,:,:)=0;coflux_SAm(35:36,:,:)=0;
coflux_SAm(:,1:3,:)=0;coflux_SAm(:,11:18,:)=0;' and now it works. With the previous one I was deleting the intersection between longitude and latitude  and not everything but what I needed...silly me. Thank you anyway if anyone bothered to have a look. Cheers!

Comment: If this is the answer to your problem, you should put it in the answer box below, and then accept that answer by clicking the green tick. This will close your question. It is how Stack Overflow works as described in the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in putting the answer here, I just saw that I had to to close the thread. I copy and paste so it can be closed. Cheers

Ok, nevermind...I was obviously being silly and getting worried about the code and not the logic behind what I really wanted. I changed the code to: 'coflux_SAm(1:26,:,:)=0;coflux_SAm(35:36,:,:)=0; coflux_SAm(:,1:3,:)=0;coflux_SAm(:,11:18,:)=0;' and now it works. With the previous one I was deleting the intersection between longitude and latitude and not everything but what I needed...silly me. Thank you anyway if anyone bothered to have a look. Cheers!